# Viewing all stories owned by a person

Tags: rally

Does anyone have any suggestions for the best / simplest way to view all stories owned by a specific user (or specific users) inside a Rally workspace?

I gather there may be ways to do this (e.g. through a Custom Grid) if there were single "parent" projects at the top of each workspace, but I'm looking for something similar without having to make "dummy" uber-parent projects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do it on a custom grid since you will be bound by the global project scope or a specific scope of your choosing in the settings panel.  This should be relatively straightforward to write as an app though (which could then be run in a custom panel on the dashboard or in a custom tab).

The App SDK's [RallyDataSource](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/rally-data-source) allows querying the entire workspace like so:

```
var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource("__WORKSPACE_OID__",
             "__PROJECT_OID__",
             "__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__",
             "__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__");

rallyDataSource.findAll({
  'type' : 'hierarchicalrequirement',
  'key' : 'myStories',
  'fetch': 'FormattedID,Name',
  'query': '(Owner = /user/__USER_OID__)', //Find items owned by me
  'order': 'FormattedID',
  'project': null //Query the entire workspace
}, 
onStoriesRetrieved); //Callback when data is available
```

It should then be straightforward to display those stories in a [Table](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/tables).